# columns not alligned side by side foundation css

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

i have the following code that should create a row with three columns side by side but the columns appear one after the other in large screen

```
<div class="row">
   <div  class= "columns large-4  small-12" style="background-color: brown;">
        <!-- <img src="photos/building.jpeg"  alt="building"> -->
        ggg
   </div>  



    <div class= "columns large-3 small-12 " style="background-color: blueviolet;">
            <!-- <img src="photos/building.jpeg"  alt="building"> -->
            bbx
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: blue;" class="columns large-3  small-12">
                <!-- <img src="photos/building.jpeg"  alt="building"> -->
                vvv
            </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: this doesnt show full column when the screen is large

Comment: instead you can make of grid-x as part of latest version , checkout this - https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you include foundation.css to your code?
Here is the example of working one (expand script):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
   <div class="columns large-4 small-12" style="background-color: brown;">ggg</div>  
   <div class="columns large-4 small-12" style="background-color: blueviolet;">bbx</div>
   <div class="columns large-4 small-12" style="background-color: blue;">vvv</div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation-float.css" integrity="sha256-h9i8L1eVkaZg4vi/+f+jUUbAulAo9wnQwZtoFHoaUEY=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.5.3/css/foundation.min.css" integrity="sha256-xpOKVlYXzQ3P03j397+jWFZLMBXLES3IiryeClgU5og=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Comment: this is not working its supposed to show three columns side by side on full screen

Comment: Which Foundation version and css file do you use?

Comment: This should work, see https://codepen.io/DanielRuf/pen/QWwyLzO?editors=1010